# Grails ACL spring-security-core:2.0-RC2,spring-security-acl-2.0-RC1

Tags: grails

I am facing a strange problem. Login controller does not get compiled whenever i run/debug my application. But as soon as i do some edit in the login controller and then save, it compiles successfully.

Is anything work arround here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
grails clean
```

Then remove `.class` in `target` folder

```
rm -rf ./target/*
```

Remove cache files in `.slcache` folder

```
rm -rf ../../../.grails/.slcache/*
```

Then run grails

```
grails run-app
```

Comment: it does not work, is it the problem of this version of acl? let be to make more clear: when i run the application for the first time then i cannot login using login controller. But after running the application when i do some edit (like adding comment or space using enter key) and save the login controller then login is successfully done. what might be the problem?